# How can I write directly to a Solaris FIFO pipe over ssh?

Tags: ssh, python, pipe, solaris, netcat

I have a Solaris server running a process that has its input and output redirected into FIFO pipes (fifo_in, fifo_out).

How can I connect to these two pipes over ssh?

I would like to be able to write to the fifo_in pipe over ssh and have the Solaris process execute the commands it receives via the pipe, and then of course to receive the output of the process via fifo_out.

I can connect to the Solaris server via ssh or ftp. Not sure if it has netcat installed, but from what I have read online it seems unlikely.

Edit: I would like to do all of this from python (on the client) so I can parse the data as it comes in from the Solaris process.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, one cannot open unix pipes directly over ssh since Python throws an IOerror. After some wrangling, I ended up doing as follows. Using Python/Paramiko I run these commands on the Solaris server (via SSH):

```
mkfifo input
sleep 10800 > input &
```

This creates the input pipe and 'sleep' makes sure that the pipe stays open (10800 is 3 hours in seconds). If you don't use sleep, the pipe will close after the first time you pass a batch of commands to it.

The I run my process, by sending this over ssh:

```
nohup process_name < input > output.txt &
```

This starts the process, attaches the input pipe to its stdin, and its output to a simple text file output.txt. nohup makes sure the process stays alive if I disconnect the ssh session.

Note: I at first intended to use an output pipe also for the output but since it turns out I cannot open pipes via SSH, there is no advantage using a pipe. I still use a pipe for the input, as this makes sure that my process continues accepting commands as I send them.

The output is easy to read from the output.txt, but for input I send each batch of commands (that I wanted the process to execute). First the Python script creates a text file with the new batch of commands called redir.txt, and then send the contents of that text file into the pipe:

```
cat redir.txt > input
```

This redirects the commands first into the input pipe, and then the process reads the commands from the pipe.